# Why does NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() give error Invalid default value when creating this table?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm upgrading to MySQL 8.0.21

In my old database, creating a table that included

```
`time_requested` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
```

worked fine. Then I could use phps strtotime('now') to insert epoch times like 1405477722.

However, when creating a table with that line in this version of MySQL, I get the error:

```
ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 15892: Invalid default value for 'time_requested'
```

What's changed between the versions? Can I no longer use current_timestamp() in an int(11) column?

Comment: What is the version of your old MySQL instance?